# Branch URL on Facebook opens Play Store instead of Android app

Tags: android, facebook, branch.io

I am having some troubles finding a way to open the Android app via the Branch link shared on Facebook. Even if I have the app installed it redirects me to Google Play Store.

I do get the branch params if I open the app (from the Google Play Store or by launching directly).  Shared on any other channel (WhatsApp, Twitter, Chrome etc.) it opens the app if it is installed.

In the dashboard I have checked: Always try to open app, defined the URI scheme < company:// >, and selected the app from Google Play Store (even tough the released version doesn’t yet have Branch added to it)

One note, my package name is like: ‘*com.company*’.

Haven’t enabled App Links. (*should not matter*)

Testing on devices with **Android 6.0.1**  (*should not matter*)

The branch URI is like the example below.

> Eg: company.test-app.link/something

In the manifest I have defined an activity with:

```
<intent-filter>
<data android:host="open" android:scheme="company" />
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
</intent-filter>
```

What am I missing?:)

Comment: Alex from Branch here: this is odd — I know opening apps from Facebook on iOS is blocked, but Android has never been an issue up until now. If you open the same link from anywhere else, does it work as expected?

Comment: Hi Florin, I'm unable to reproduce your issue (both regular and app links are working directly from native FB for me on Android). Please write in to integrations@branch.io and I can offer additional support!

Comment: @AlexBauer Working as expected from anywhere else.

Comment: found out what was wrong. My URI scheme was starting with a number, and the facebook viewer added encoding %3 in front of the uri => no app found.